# Giving an answer, which is an exact copy (a duplicate) of my own blog article

Tags: discussion, copyright

Can I use, as an answer, an exact duplicate of an article from my own blog, when I authored 100% text of that article and all possible modifications (because I'm the only author publishing on that blog)?

My blog even uses Markdown, so that would be a nearly exact copy-paste, with tiny or no changes.

My blog has an "*About*" section, where I clearly state, that with my directly expressed agreement texts from that blog may be used on any site, with clear statement of copyrights / author / text owner etc.

If this is allowed, then what statement or other copyright / copyless / legal blah blah -- except for a link to source -- I'm requested to include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a sample part of a site and paste it in here. If you are not violating the terms of usage of that site then there is no problem about taking something from somewhere else.

What is important for Stack Exchange sites is, your answer should be a whole and understandable answer. You also should reference the source site or the post in the related site along with the author of the writing if it do not belong to you.

[Here is the related documentation section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If you do not own the related post, then re-writing the text with your own words is better, but if you own the post and the post exactly contains what the question had asked then you can copy paste it as is.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers have addressed the legalities -- it's your work, so yes you can use it without further attribution etc, understanding that henceforth it will be licensed CC-BY-SA.  But you should consider making the connection explicit anyway.

Some users on SE, when encountering something that looks "too well-written" or that raises other mental flags, will search the web for a sample of the text.  If somebody does that to one of your answers and finds the blog, it could look like plagiarism.  Don't rely on people to check your SE profile and your blog's "about me" page to match up the names.  Some people will, but some won't.  On a low-volume site a moderator handling a plagiarism flag might do that investigation, but on a high-volume site?  Not something I'd want to rely on.

Fortunately, this is easy to address.  The phrase "As I wrote on my blog" or similar will declare to readers that no, you're not ripping off some other blogger.  You can even include the link; that kind of promotion is ok if you answer the question here on SE.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the copyright you enforce on your text, but since you are the owner of the content, you can do with it what you want. You are free to redistribute in on another license (specifically: the license SE uses) .

Note that users there are free to redistribute your answer if they comply to the SE license, not the license on your site.